# Google Adwards shows way more installs than I actual have...?

Tags: google-play, ads, google-ads-api

Here is the complete situation:

I've launched an app a few days ago and connected it to my own server. When the app is opened for the first time (or even after that), it calls my server api and stores the device id, region, and timestamp. On the other side, I also started a campaign for Ad installs on Google Adwards.

Until today everything looked connected in terms of the install it was showing on Google Adwards vs my own server but what happened today is a bit shocking for me... I checked on my Google Adwards account and there were 450 installs only for today (and total were around 750) against that campaign but according to my server DB, there are around 130 installs today which also has some part from Facebook campaign. So, it's 100% clear that the data Google Adwards shows and what they charged me for isn't correct.

What is the best way to report it? also, they don't seem to be reliable now...

Comment: I have the same issue. Google Ads shows 56 installs, while in my database it is only 6 installs. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Your server DB probably only records users that opened your app. Whereas Adwords installs probably records users who installed it. Is it possible the different ways of measuring are both correct?

Are you tracking ["First open" in your Adwords](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6255257)?